# Create a column in SQL that shows if specific month is between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, case, between

I want to add a column to the results, for every month. The column should contain true if it is between two dates (dates come from the same row).

For example I have date from = 2023-01-01 and date to = 2023-05-31

So I want that 2023-02 column would get value = 1 because this month is between those dates

But column 2023-06 would get value = 0, because this month is out of range.

Now I have table

| Customer nr | Date from | Date to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xxxxxx | 2023-01-01 | 2023-05-31 |
| yyyyyy | 2023-03-01 | 2023-10-31 |
| qqqqqq | 2023-08-01 | 2023-12-31 |

But I want to have:

| Customer nr | Date from | Date to | 2023.01 | 2023.02 | 2023.03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxxxxx | 2023-01-01 | 2023-05-31 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| yyyyyy | 2023-03-01 | 2023-10-31 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| qqqqq | 2023-08-01 | 2023-12-31 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Do you mean add the columns to a query result based on a list of dates?

Comment: Do you want to create the columns in the table or is this just a query result you want ?

Comment: Dates support greater than (`>`) and less than (`<`) logic; why didn't your attempt to use such logic work?

Comment: Stack Overflow questions shouldn't just state "I want". You also have to tell what you tried and explain the actual problem you faced. We can't answer questions if there's no problem to solve.

Comment: So every new year you want to create some new columns? I think this is a not so great idea, database theory says that one shouldn't create columns containing data which can be derived from other columns, and usually it's a good rule to follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `date_from` is always first day of month and `date_to` is always last date of month then use a simple `between` check:

```
select *
     , case when '2023-01-01' between date_from and date_to then 1 else 0 end as [2023-01]
     , case when '2023-02-01' between date_from and date_to then 1 else 0 end as [2023-02]
     , case when '2023-03-01' between date_from and date_to then 1 else 0 end as [2023-03]
from t;
```

Otherwise use range overlap check (some part of the month intersects some part of the [date_from, date_to] range):

```
select *
     , case when date_to >= '2023-01-01' AND date_from <= eomonth('2023-01-01') then 1 else 0 end as [2023-01]
     , case when date_to >= '2023-02-01' AND date_from <= eomonth('2023-02-01') then 1 else 0 end as [2023-02]
     , case when date_to >= '2023-03-01' AND date_from <= eomonth('2023-03-01') then 1 else 0 end as [2023-03]
from t;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sodzace4)

Comment: The question was unclear and I regret it has been answered prematurely. People actually benefit from being forced to express clearly what they want. "I want to create column" is not an example of that. Also, this solution clearly is suboptimal because it requires a code change whenever a month should be added. IMO we should have guided OP in the direction of pivoting.

Comment: @gert "want to create column" is something I encounter often and people actually mean add an expression to the result. I will edit the question. And I disagree with pivoting idea, there are 12 months in a year. No need to split data into 12 rows only to consoliate it back.